# Can I end a sentence with "is"?

Tags: be, academia, sentence-ends

I am writing a research paper and intend to write this sentence :

> Even a cursory reading of the news reveals how grossly inaccurate that assumption is.

Is that an accurate and appropriate sentence for an academic paper?

Comment: Yes, it’s fine. It really is. I don’t see what the problem with *is* is.

Comment: If your sentence isn't correct, then what is ?

Comment: If it bothers you, try _… reveals the gross inaccuracy of that assumption_. Has a better sense of cadence.

Comment: Now we just find out who the person that created this stigma is.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that ending a sentence with "is" is verboten. Thanks for the response.